# WPF App Ignore High Contrast

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to ignore High Contrast change in WPF application?

In windows OS, Go to settings -> Ease of Access -> Change High Contrast. Application visualization is changed to High Contrast color. I need to avoid this.

Comment: You may have a good reason for this, but remember the user has good reasons to enable high contrast too... do you really plan to ignore the users decision? I recommend you support high contrast if it is conflicting with your current visuals. That being said, I really don't know how to do what you request, else I would answer.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for your response. Yes, We need to ignore user decision of High Contrast setting because we have internal theme settings inside our app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Simple! You need to overwrite the default style.